# Cannot center align images with text in div

Tags: html, css, web

I am trying to create a footer for a website with links to social media accounts, but I'm having trouble centering the images.

The text is centered correctly, but clearly the images are not, they are closer to the right.

Here's what it looks like this:
[image]

```css
.footer {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: green;
}

.footer ul{
  list-style: none;
}

.footer ul li {
  font-size: 26px;
  display: inline-block; 
  background-color: red;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}

.footer a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding-left:10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer a:hover {
  color: orangered;
}
.footer p{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.footer img{
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0.7;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
.footer img:hover{
  opacity: 1.0;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <ul>   
    <li><a href="mailto:bannermangavin@gmail.com"><img src="/resources/email.png" alt="mail"></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://uk.linkedin.com/in/gavin-bannerman" target="_blank"><img src="/resources/linkedin.png" alt="linkedin page"></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://github.com/gavinbannerman" target="_blank"><img src="/resources/github.png" alt="github page"></a></li>
  </ul>
  <p>Copyright Company Name &copy; 2016 | All Rights Reserved</p>
</div>
```

I have already searched multiple threads, even copying the code, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Here's a fiddle with my work: https://jsfiddle.net/p64q1aru/

Comment: if you don't specify the padding and margin for some elements like <h1> and  <ul> you will get default, browser-injected styling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ul (list) has padding-left that needs to be reset:

```
.footer ul {
   list-style:none;
   padding:0;
}
```

Removing the padding resolves the issue and centralises your list elements.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given the `vertical-align`:

```
.footer img {
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0.7;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;   /* This is important. */
}
```

And please use reset.

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

> *I have already searched multiple threads, even copying the code, but I can't seem to get it to work.*

If this is true, you have done everything without knowing the use of them.

**Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pnkocs9d/**

Comment: I have tried adding the vertical align but I don't understand how that would affect the horizontal alignment? It doesn't seem to have sorted it.

Comment: @GBannerman Okay, I thought it was both horizontal and vertical. Tell me if the fiddle I posted works good for you?

Comment: It's not vertical alignment that's at issue here, for sure.

Comment: @NathanielFlick Yea, I targeted both vertical and horizontal.

Comment: @GBannerman Check https://jsfiddle.net/pnkocs9d/ and tell me if it works?

Comment: Thank you, resetting the margins and padding was my issue.

Answer (score 0):

you should reset the default padding of `ul` element try to add padding:0

```
.footer ul{
    list-style: none;
  padding:0
}
```

[Updated Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/p64q1aru/3/)

Answer (score 0):

To best control the spacing make sure padding and margin are zero on the ul and remove any line breaks/spacing between list items. Then you can use padding on each icon image to set spacing evenly (I haven't done this part).

```css
.footer {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: green;
}

.footer ul{
    list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: blue;
}

.footer ul li {
    display: inline-block;  
    background-color: red;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}

.footer a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.footer a:hover {
    color: orangered;
}
.footer p{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

img {
border: 1px solid red;
  font-size: 9px;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
    <ul>   
        <li><a href="mailto:bannermangavin@gmail.com"><img src="/resources/email.png" alt="mail"></a></li><li><a href="https://uk.linkedin.com/in/gavin-bannerman" target="_blank"><img src="/resources/linkedin.png" alt="linkedin page"></a></li><li><a href="https://github.com/gavinbannerman" target="_blank"><img src="/resources/github.png" alt="github page"></a></li>
    </ul>
    <p>Copyright Company Name &copy; 2016 | All Rights Reserved</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Add the css rules for `UL`

```
padding-left: 0;
```

```css
.footer {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: green;
}

.footer ul{
 padding-left: 0;
    list-style: none;

}

.footer ul li {
    font-size: 26px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: red;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}

.footer a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.footer a:hover {
    color: orangered;
}
.footer p{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.footer img{
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0.7;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    margin: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
.footer img:hover{
    opacity: 1.0;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="mailto:bannermangavin@gmail.com"><img src="10.png" width="15px" height="10px" alt="mail"></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://uk.linkedin.com/in/gavin-bannerman" target="_blank"><img src="10.png" width="15px" height="10px" alt="mail"></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://github.com/gavinbannerman" target="_blank"><img src="10.png" width="15px" height="10px" alt="mail"></a></li>
    </ul>
    <p>Copyright Company Name &copy; 2016 | All Rights Reserved</p>
</div>
```